# Change current directory with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a command line utility in node.js. As one of the features it should change the current working directory of the shell it was called from. Something like node.js version of `cd`. Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

---

To clarify, I'd like to be able to change the current directory in the terminal window by running the script.

```
/some/path> ...
/some/path> nodecd /other/path
/other/path> ...
```

The problem is that `process.chdir()` works for the SCRIPT directory, not for the SHELL directory. I need to be able to somehow pass the current shell through the bash invocation to node script, and alter the path of that shell within the script - creating a subshell won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short: you can't. The working directory is limited to the context of a process (and perhaps child processes, but certainly not parent processes). So the cwd of your Node process cannot propagate back to your shell process.

A common trick is to have your Node app print the working directory to stdout, and have your shell run your Node app like this:

```
cd "$(node app)"
```

A simple test case:

```
// app.js
console.log('/tmp');
```

And if you create a shell alias/function for it, it should be relatively painless.

Answer (score 11):

To make it clear, you cannot change the pwd of the parent process. However you might change the working directory and start a shell in that folder.

---

You need to use `process.chdir()`:

```
console.log('Starting directory: ' + process.cwd());
try {
  process.chdir('/tmp');
  console.log('New directory: ' + process.cwd());
}
catch (err) {
  console.log('chdir: ' + err);
}
```

This example is taken from the manual. [Here you can find the manual](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory).

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve the problem. It only changes the SCRIPT working directory, while I need to change the directory of the shell in which the script was invoked. See the added explanation.

Comment: This is impossible. A child cannot change the environment of his father

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar and I managed to do this by letting your Node script write the native command to a file and then execute it.

The following example will randomly move up either one or two directories. Put these two files in the same directory:

**index.js**

```js
import fs from "fs";

const nativeCommand = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "cd .." : "cd ../..";
console.log(`Executing ${nativeCommand}`);

fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/command`, nativeCommand);
```

**cli-tool.cmd**

```
@echo off
set FILE_PATH=%~p0index.js
node %FILE_PATH% %*

set /p COMMAND=< %~p0\command
%COMMAND%
```

**Run it**

```sh
C:/users/johndoe/projects/cli-tool
> ./cli-tool.cmd
Executing cd ../..

C:/users/johndoe
>
```